# how do I wait for an element to exist in a casper test?

Tags: coffeescript, phantomjs, casperjs

```
casper.test.begin "Can open the homepage", (test) ->
  casper.options.viewportSize = {width: 1024, height: 768}
  casper.start("http://localhost:4000/", ->
    @wait(1000, ->
      test.assertHttpStatus 200
      test.assertTitle("XYZ Corp")
      test.assertExists('DIV.links')
      test.assertElementCount('DIV.links', 1)
      test.assertExists('IMG#companyLogo')
      @capture('./test/screencaps/homepage.png')
    )
  ).run ->
    test.done()
```

OK so that test is passing just fine. The thing I'd like to improve is the @wait call, it seemed smarter to do @waitFor:

```
@waitFor(
  ->
    document.querySelectorAll('DIV.links').length > 0
  ->
    test.assertHttpStatus 200
    test.assertTitle("XYZ Corp")
```

However this always times out. The `document` object is present, it can run the `querySelectorAll` function, but I never get any results back. The `DIV.links` object must be present on the page (and I can see it in the screenshot) because the test is passing in the first case. But in the second case, the condition is always false. `waitFor` documentation is [here](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#waitfor).

Bonus question: can I debug casper tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 days, no answer, figured it out on my own:

```
  .then( ->
    @open("theUrl")    
    @waitUntilVisible("DIV.alpha",
    ->
      test.assertExists("DIV.alpha") # doesnt hurt to check
      test.assertExists("DIV#beta")
      @capture('./test/screencaps/waitUntilVisible.png')
    ->
      test.fail('failed to find div.alpha')
    3000
    )
  )
```